# Chart with cumulative data

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

Im having some trouble with SSRS and manipulating a chart expression to show exactly the data that I want. I'll try and explain what I want to achieve, and how I have gone about achieving it.

**What I need**
Basically I am attempting to achieve a chart where there are two lines present. They are both cumulative billing figures, one for this financial year, and one for the last. This allows me to compare this years performance with the previous year.

**What I have done**
The first stumbling block was in ensuring that the x-axis was structured in such a way that the data would be relevant whatever the year. Just using the transaction date doesnt work because this would result in the lines not overlapping each other, with one on the left, and one on the right. To combat this the data source has a column 'month' which is the month number (1-Jan, 2-Feb etc).

I then set about setting up two value expressions for the chart. I have nested an 'IIF' statement in a 'RunningValue' statement. The RunningValue gives me a cumulative total, and the IIF only returns values to be accumulated if it meets the date criterea. This is effectively the current year cumulative total.

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!InvoiceDateRaw.Value > #04/30
/2012#,Fields!Net_Amount.Value,1),Sum,Nothing)
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work. To throw a massive spanner in the works, it does work for this line if I set a data filter on the properties of the data set. Very strange.

Any help gratefully received.